# How to make a range slider's thumb in big circular shape and make it appear over the slider track?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rangeslider

My code is almost ready but I am stuck at one point. It is a range slider with custom values. Means when we move its thumb, it will show the values we have entered in code.

[This is how I want slider and its thumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw5bu.png)

But this is what till now I am able to achieve- [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5oKo.png)

This is the code I am using here-
HTML:

```
<p style='background-color:teal; width:300px; height:250px;'>Number: <output id="ageValue">28</output><br/></br>
<input id="ageSlider" class='range' type="range" min="25" max="30" step="1" value="28" oninput="ageSliderChange(this.value)" onmousemove="ageSliderChange(this.value)" style="width: 200px"></br></br>
Output: <output id="premiumValue">4,565</output><br/>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.range{
-webkit-appearance: none;
 height:10px; 
 width:15px; 
 border-radius:15px; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 outline:none;
}
.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none;
background:gray;
width:12px; 
height:12px; 
border-radius:50%;
box-shadow:-407px 0 0 400px #fda62d;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function ageSliderChange(ageSlider) {

var age = document.getElementById("ageSlider").value

document.getElementById('ageValue').innerHTML = ageSlider;

    if (age == 25) {
        document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '3,740'
        } 
        else if(age == 26){
        document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '3,863'
        } 
        else if(age == 27){
        document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '4,004'
        }
        else if(age == 28){
        document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '4,167'
        } 
        else if(age == 29){
        document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '4,353'
        } 
        else if(age == 30){
        document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '4,565'
        } 
        else {
        document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = ''
            }
    }
```

Now what's the proper solution to make a slider thumb bigger and make it appear circular over the track like shown in first image?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't do it with regular css. `::-webkit-slider-thumb` is a pseudo element. These kind of elements are not part of the DOM and difficult to manipulate. better completely replace the thumb with another element and change the height width of that element.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add a custom style element whose size you can change using JS code. I have added a function to change the style so that you can leverage that to change the style dynamically if needed.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("ageSlider");
var style = document.querySelector('[data="test"]');

setData(50); // set value in this function to make your thumb bigger or smaller.


function setData(x) {
  style.innerHTML = ".range::-webkit-slider-thumb { width: " + x + "px !important; height: " + x + "px !important; }";
}

function ageSliderChange(ageSlider) {

  var age = document.getElementById("ageSlider").value

  document.getElementById('ageValue').innerHTML = ageSlider;

  if (age == 25) {
    document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '3,740'
  } else if (age == 26) {
    document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '3,863'
  } else if (age == 27) {
    document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '4,004'
  } else if (age == 28) {
    document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '4,167'
  } else if (age == 29) {
    document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '4,353'
  } else if (age == 30) {
    document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = '4,565'
  } else {
    document.getElementById("premiumValue").innerHTML = ''
  }
}
```

```css
.range {
  margin-top: 40px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
}

.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p style='background-color:teal; width:300px; height:250px;'>Number: <output id="ageValue">28</output><br/></br>
  <!--Add your custom style element here which we will change using JS -->
  <style data="test" type="text/css"></style>
  <input id="ageSlider" class='range' type="range" min="25" max="30" step="1" value="28" oninput="ageSliderChange(this.value)" onmousemove="ageSliderChange(this.value)" style="width: 200px"></br>
  </br>
  Output: <output id="premiumValue">4,565</output><br/>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi @sandeep joshi, Thanks for the help.
I think I should have mentioned this earlier that the slider needs to be divided into two colors. Kindly see the images once again. While this perfectly solves my slider thumb issue, but at the same time the background color of the slider track got converted into a single color. **The left part of the background Color on the track needs to move with slider thumb and leaving remaining right side part in white color.** This is requirement. Kindly help.